# keyboard hotkeys on as default when I boot my pc

Tags: keyboard

I have hotkeys on my keyboard that act as shortcut buttons to change volume, screen brightness, keyboard brigthness and so on. They double as function keys too, I can change the feature on/off with fn+esc. When I boot my pc the function button is on by default, I want to make it so that function keys are off and hotkeys are on everytime I boot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can be set from within the Ubuntu OS. If available, this will be a setting in your computer's BIOS. Consult the manual of your computer to see how you can boot into the computer's BIOS settings, and browse through these to see if the setting is available.